# NetBeans 8 not including external Librariies FXML Java (deploying JAR)

Tags: netbeans, javafx, fxml

I've seen this come up various times in other ones but they usually have a solution that has to edit the build.xml file, the problem is that I dont see that file anywhere on my netBeans project. 
I made a javafx appliation using Netbeans, as of now everything is working fine and when i clean and build and go to the dist folder and double click on the jar file it works fine, however the dist folder has the following 3 files:

```
<project name>.html
<project name>.jar
<project name>.jnlp
```

[image: Project FXML]
no lib folder or anything of the sort.
I also made sure to go to the project properties > build > packaging > and check
Compress Jar file
Build JAR after compiling
Copy dependent libraries

all 3 are checked. 
When I move this jar file to another machine that has the same JRE version (version 8) it doesnt open, it doesnt do anything and I am making the assumption is because there are no libraries.
Why am I making this assumption>? 
because usually when another person gives me a JAR file it comes in a folder with a lib subfolder and mine has nothing, its just a standalone jar file.
Again, I've seen similar issues but none of them are Java FXML specific, which seems to be different than regular java

**NEW EDIT**
I tried running it through the command prompt in windows (in the other computer)
I get this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at at.qcresponsetime.ATQCResponseTime.start(ATQCResponseTime.java:22)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 35 more
Exception running application at.qcresponsetime.ATQCResponseTime
```

Comment: Can you try running from a command prompt (windows) or terminal (linux) and see if you get any meaningful message? Also - please check the exact JRE version (8u60? 8u45? 8u131? etc.), and provide any info about the differences between the machines (OS + version, hardware etc)

Comment: @sillyfly see OP edit, I tried running it through the command prompt as you mentioned and I got that error. it mentions the gnu.io which is the TXRX external library I'm using which is what I think is the problem.

Comment: Have you thought about using a build-tool instead of the IDE-provided solution? Maybe the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) (I'm the maintainer of that project) or the [javafx-gradle-project](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) (I'm the author of that project). They would take care about the required dependencies.